# To prove that a process is strictly stationary

Tags: random-variables, stationary-processes

I have been given $ \{X_n;n>0\}$ as a sequence of i.i.d random variables and we another sequence  $ \{Y_n;n>0\}$ defined such that $$Y_n=X_n+aX_{n-1}$$ where a is a real constant

I need to show that  $ \{Y_n;n>0\}$ is a strictly stationary process. Now my usual approach to prove a strictly stationary process is to prove that the all the random variables $Y_n$ are independent but I don't think this is necessarily true in this case since the sum of iid RVs is not necessarily an iid itself.

Any hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Isn't it easy to see that since the $X_n$'s are iid RV's, the distribution of $Y_n$, $P(Y_n=y)$ does not depend on $n$? It is very easy to construct it given the distribution of the $X$'s.

Comment: Intuitively I can see that the distribution of $Y_n$ will independent of n but I was wondering if there's any formal way to prove this without knowing the distribution of the X's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is strictly stationary (independence, as you mention). It is left to verify that the function which maps $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ to $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}$ behaves “well” when you shift the argument. I will leave you to discover what “well” means here.

**EDIT:**

The above was a hint. Since it might not have been entirely clear what I meant I decided to provide a full solution as well.

Firstly, it is not clear how $Y_1$ is defined. If one were to define $Y_1:=X_1$ then $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is *not* strictly stationary (unless $a=0$). To get strict stationarity one has to introduce $X_0$ which is independent of $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ and has the same distribution as $X_1$. Then the definition of $Y_n$ also makes sense for $n=1$. Notation wise, however, this is a bit annoying since the sequences $\{X_n\}_{n\geq0}$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}$ start at different index. Instead I think the best fix is to change the definition of $Y_n$ slightly. I will define $Y'_n:=X_{n+1}+aX_n$. Note that $\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}\sim\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}$ so we may prove strict stationarity for $\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}$ instead.

For $N\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\theta^N$ be the function which maps a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}$ of real numbers to the shifted sequence $\{x_{N+n}\}_{n\geq1}$. By definition $\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is strictly stationary if $\theta^N(\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1})\sim\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

As I mention it is fairly obvious that $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is strictly stationary because it is an i.i.d. sequence. Since the this is simple to prove I am happy to do it here. To show that $\theta^N(\{X_n\}_{n\geq1})\sim\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we must prove that all finite dimensional distributions are identical. We take integers $0\leq n_1<n_2<\dotsc<n_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{B}$ and immediately see that
$$
(X_{N+n_1},\dotsc,X_{N+n_m})\sim(X_{n_1},\dotsc,X_{n_m}).
$$
Indeed, since the $X_n$'s are i.i.d. the left- and right-hand side both have distribution $P_{X_1}^{\otimes m}$ (product measure of $P_{X_1}$ $m$ times), where $P_{X_1}$ is the distribution of $X_1$.

We will then consider the function $f$ which maps $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ to $\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}$. To be precise
$$
f(\{x_n\}_{n\geq1})_m=x_{m+1}+ax_{m}
$$
for $m\in\mathbb{N}$. This function has an important property, namely that $f\circ\theta^N=\theta^N\circ f$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Indeed,
$$
f(\theta^N(\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}))_m=x_{N+m+1}+ax_{N+m}=\theta^N(f(\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}))_m
$$
for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

The stationarity of $\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is obtained from the observations above. We simply see that
$$
\theta^N(\{Y'_n\}_{n\geq1})=\theta^N(f(\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}))=f(\theta^N(\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}))\sim f(\{X_n\}_{n\geq1})=\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}
$$
for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the author of the OP requested an explicit statement of the stationarity, let us construct the distribution of the $Y_n$'s. Define the probability density $F(X_n=x)=f(x)$

$$F(Y_n=y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dx_n dx_{n-1}\delta(x_n+ax_{n-1}-y)f(x_n)f(x_{n-1})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dwf(y-aw)f(w)$$

which shows that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}~~$,$~~F(Y_{n+N}=y)=F(Y_n=y)$.

**EDIT:** It is correct, as stated in a comment, that the statement above is not enough to prove strict stationarity, but it is a key ingredient thereof. To actually prove the strict stationarity of the sequence, it suffices to show that

$$ F_Y(Y_2=y_2,..., Y_n=y_n)=F_Y(Y_{N+2}=y_2,Y_{N+3}=y_3,..., Y_{N+n}=y_n), ~~\forall ~n, N $$

where the $Y_n, n\geq 2$ are defined as above. The reason why this is sufficient is because strict stationarity for an arbitrary set of times ${t_i}$ can be obtained by considering the joint distribution $F_Y(Y_2..., Y_{\max_i t_i})$ and integrating out the times inbetween that do not belong to the set.

In the following I have set $Y_1:=X_1$, because the law of the set $Y_1,Y_2,..., Y_n$ is easily constructible, but eventually stationarity has to be proven without the contribution of $X_1$. Now we just need to construct the probability measure above, which can be done iteratively:

$$F_Y(Y_1=y_1, ..., Y_n=y_n)=F(Y_n|Y_1,..., Y_{n-1})F_Y(Y_1,..., Y_{n-1})$$

The conditional density can be easily computed by independence and the definition of $Y_n$ and the final result is

$$F_Y(Y_1=y_1, ..., Y_n=y_n)=\prod_{k=1}^nf\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^k y_{\ell}(-a)^{k-\ell} \right)\\=f(y_1)f(y_2-ay_1)...f(y_n-ay_{n-1}+\dots+(-a)^ny_1)$$

and thus

$$F_Y(Y_2=y_2,..., Y_n=y_n)=\int dq f(q)f(y_2-aq)...f(y_n-ay_{n-1}+\dots+(-a)^n q)$$

We can now prove the asserted statement. First note that for $N=1$ the statement is true since

$$F_Y(Y_3=y_3,..., Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1})\\=\int dy_1 dy_2f(y_1)f(y_2-ay_1)...f(y_{n+1}-ay_{n}+\dots+(-a)^{n}y_1)\\=\int dt_1 dt_2 f(t_1) f(t_2) f(y_3-at_2)... f(y_{n+1}-ay_n...+(-a)^{n-2}y_3+(-a)^{n-1} t_2)\\=\int dt_2  f(t_2) f(y_3-at_2)... f(y_{n+1}-ay_n...+(-a)^{n-2}y_3+(-a)^{n-1} t_2)=F_Y(Y_2=y_3, ..., Y_n=y_{n+1})$$

Now we perform a similar substitution in the integral for any $N$ and show in a similar manner that

$$F_Y(Y_{N+2}=y_{N+2},..., Y_{N+n}=y_{N+n})\\=\int dy_1...dy_{N+1} f(y_1)...f(y_{N+1}-...+(-a)^{N}y_1)...f(y_{N+n}-...+(-a)^ny_N+...+(-a)^{N+n-1}y_1)$$

Which by setting $t_{N+1}=y_{N+1}-ay_N+...+(-a)^N y_1$ and noting that

$$\int dy_1...dy_N f(y_1)f(y_2-ay_1)...f(y_N-...+(-a)^{N-1}y_1)=1$$

shows that

$$F_Y(Y_{N+2}=y_{N+2},..., Y_{N+n}=y_{N+n})=F_Y(Y_{2}=y_{N+2},..., Y_{n}=y_{N+n})$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: Firstly, the distribution of $Y_n$ is not specified by the probabilities $P(Y_n=y)$ (this probability may very well be zero for all $y$). Secondly, it is not
 sufficient to show that the distribution of $Y_n$ does not depend on $n$. For $\{Y_n\}$ to be strictly stationary the distribution of the entire sequence must be shift-invariant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited with a complete proof. Even though it's hard to accept it from someone who decided to write a cryptic 3-liner in response to a question with a not so obvious answer.

Comment: I provided a hint since the OP specifically asked for that. You calling it "a cryptic 3-liner" tells me that I was not successful. I have edited my answer to also include the solution I was hinting at.
I notice that you have now edited your solution to cover finite dimensional distributions. However, you assume existence of Lebesgue densities. Generally (and it is not hard to give an example) such densities do not exist.